# Problem parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I encounter problems tring to consume a third party web servive in JSON format. The JSON response from the server kinda looks like this:

```
{
    "ID":10079,
    "DateTime":new Date(1288384200000),
    "TimeZoneID":"W. Europe Standard Time",
    "groupID":284,
    "groupOrderID":10
}
```

I use JavaScript with no additional libs to parse the JSON.

```
//Parse JSON string to JS Object            
var messageAsJSObj = JSON.parse(fullResultJSON);
```

The parsing fails. A JSON validatior tells me, "new Date(1288384200000)" is not valid.

Is there a library which could help me parse the JSON string?

Comment: `new Date(1288384200000)` is a JavaScript command that is probably intended to be executed directly. Can't think of a way to do this except `var = eval(data);` This is not proper JSON, you should complain about this to the third party

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like others have pointed out, it's invalid JSON.  One solution is to use `eval()` instead of `JSON.parse()` but that leaves you with a potential security issue instead.

A better approach might be to search for and replace these offending issues, turning the data into valid JSON:

```
fullResultJSON = fullResultJSON.replace(/new Date\((\d+)\)/g, '$1');
```

You can even go one step further and "revive" these fields into JavaScript Date objects using the second argument for `JSON.parse()`:

```
var messageAsJSObj = JSON.parse(fullResultJSON, function (key, value) {
    if (key == "DateTime")
        return new Date(value);

    return value;
});
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/vcXnE/

Answer (score 3):

Your example is not valid JSON, since JSON is a data exchange technology. You can turn your example into a Javascript object using `eval`:

```
var almostJSON = "{
    "ID":10079,
    "DateTime":new Date(1288384200000),
    "TimeZoneID":"W. Europe Standard Time",
    "groupID":284,
    "groupOrderID":10,
}";
```

and then `eval`ing it:

```
var myObject = eval('(' + almostJSON + ')');
```

Then, `myObject` should hold what you're looking for.

Note that functions are not allowed in JSON because that could compromise security.

Comment: It looks a little bit insecure to me, just to evaluate anything coming from a remote peer.

Comment: @scheffield: that's true. If you expect valid JSON from a third party and get something like this, you have a valid reason to be suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

try var obj = eval('(' + fullResultJSON + ')'); and you'll have the object like Pekka said. Don't forget to use the extra '()' though. And indeed json should have both property and value enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing fails because all you can parse in a json object are null, strings, numbers, objects, arrays and boolean values so `new Date(1288384200000)`, cannot be parsed

You have also another problem, last property shouldn't have the trailing comma.

Comment: jsonlint tells the json is formally invalid with last comma.

Comment: @fcalderan: never mind me, my brain had a small meltdown.  Of course, JSON and JS Object literals aren't the same thing and the trailing comma is indeed invalid.  However, he may have (and probably did) just chopped the JSON result down to the relevant part without removing the comma from the last item.